# error Couldn't find a package.json file in "/server"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-build

I updated docker on my mac and I can't seem to run this image on my localhost. I'm getting the error: Couldn't find a package.json file in "/server"

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks!

I run both yaml files with:
`docker-compose -f docker-compose.base.yaml -f docker-compose.local.yaml up -d`

**docker-compose.base.yaml:**

```
version: '3.0'

volumes:
  mongo:

networks:
  main:

services:

  server:
    build:
      context: server
    networks:
      - main
    depends_on:
      - mongo

  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    volumes:
      - mongo:/data/db
    ports:
      - 27071:27017
    networks:
      - main
```

**docker-compose.local.yaml**

```
version: '3.0'

services:

  server:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.local
    ports:
      - 5601:80
    volumes:
      - ./server:/server
```

Dockerfile.local

```
FROM node:lts
WORKDIR /server
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT [ "yarn", "run", "start:local" ]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share what is in `Dockerfile.local` and the directory structure of your `./server` volume?

Comment: @kthompso Sure. Updated post above.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Interesting, I've seen a few issues regarding an update and Docker for mac not being happy. Can you overwrite the `CMD` of the container with something such as `["sleep", "infinity"]` and then use `docker exec -it container_id sh` to navigate to the mounted folder and show the files and permissions?

Comment: I'm not that proficient in docker. How can I go into the mounted container if I can't run it from the image? If there is way please be so kind and provide exact command I should execute in order. Thanks

Comment: I fixed it by adding CMD cd server just before the ENTRYPOINT in the dockerfile. My other docker image had the same issue and new package.json generated from npm install fixed the issue without this new line item.